# CS1674 'IEnumerator': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#, idisposable, ienumerator

I have to maintain an old project in my company which is coded using C# and old .NET Framework (maybe 2.0?) many years ago. I loaded old source files to Visual Studio and it gives me an error: "**CS1674 'IEnumerator': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'**" when I try to build it.

Here's a complete function which causes this error, most importantly this part: "**using (IEnumerator enumerator = dataTable.Rows.GetEnumerator())**", any advice how to get rid of it?

I tried to read other similar questions but I could not solve this with them. Is there maybe alternative way to code this, or could my programming environment be a cause for this?

```
    public void CompileDynamicCode()
    {
        base.Session.trace_enter();
        try
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dataTable = this.ChimneyTable;
                if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.oChimneys = new Chimney[dataTable.Rows.Count];
                    int num = 0;

                    using (IEnumerator enumerator = dataTable.Rows.GetEnumerator())
                    {
                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            DataRow dataRow = (DataRow)enumerator.Current;
                            bool entryXRight = false;
                            bool posXRight = false;
                            bool calcSteps = true;
                            bool calcCatwalk = true;
                            bool calcPlatform = true;
                            bool calcFlashing = true;
                            int connectCatwalkTo = -1;
                            if ((int)dataRow["entryXFromRight"] == 1)
                            {
                                entryXRight = true;
                            }
                            if ((int)dataRow["posXFromRight"] == 1)
                            {
                                posXRight = true;
                            }
                            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("calcSteps") && (int)dataRow["calcSteps"] == 0)
                            {
                                calcSteps = false;
                            }
                            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("calcCatwalk") && (int)dataRow["calcCatwalk"] == 0)
                            {
                                calcCatwalk = false;
                            }
                            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("calcPlatform") && (int)dataRow["calcPlatform"] == 0)
                            {
                                calcPlatform = false;
                            }
                            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("calcFlashing") && (int)dataRow["calcFlashing"] == 0)
                            {
                                calcFlashing = false;
                            }
                            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("catwalkConnection"))
                            {
                                connectCatwalkTo = (int)dataRow["catwalkConnection"];
                            }
                            this.oChimneys[num] = new Chimney((int)dataRow["index"], (int)dataRow["shape_index"], (int)dataRow["entry_shape_index"], (int)dataRow["entryX"], entryXRight, (int)dataRow["posX"], posXRight, (int)dataRow["posY"], (int)dataRow["sizeX"], (int)dataRow["sizeY"], (int)dataRow["sizeZ"], (ChimneyAccessTypeEnum)dataRow["access_type"], calcSteps, calcCatwalk, calcPlatform, calcFlashing, connectCatwalkTo, this);
                            num++;
                        }
                        goto IL_247;
                    }
                }
                this.oChimneys = new Chimney[0];
                IL_247:
                dataTable = this.ShapeTable;
                if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.oShapes = new BasicShape[dataTable.Rows.Count];
                    int num2 = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow dataRow2 in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        this.oShapes[num2] = new BasicShape((TopRowModeEnum)dataRow2["TopRowMode"], (EaveRowModeEnum)dataRow2["EaveRowMode"], (ShapeBehaviorEnum)dataRow2["Behavior"], num2, this);
                        num2++;
                    }
                }
                dataTable = this.ConnectorTable;
                if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.oConnectors = new Connector[dataTable.Rows.Count];
                    int num3 = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow dataRow3 in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        BasicShape selectShape = null;
                        BasicShape selectShape2 = null;
                        try
                        {
                            selectShape = this.oShapes[(int)dataRow3["Shape1Index"]];
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            selectShape2 = this.oShapes[(int)dataRow3["Shape2Index"]];
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                        this.oConnectors[num3] = new Connector((ConnectorBehaviorEnum)dataRow3["ConnectorBehavior"], selectShape, selectShape2, (ShapeConnectingLineEnum)dataRow3["Shape1Line"], (ShapeConnectingLineEnum)dataRow3["Shape2Line"], this, num3, (ConnectorStartEndMode)dataRow3["StartMode"], (ConnectorStartEndMode)dataRow3["StopMode"]);
                        num3++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                base.Session.HandleException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
            this.DynamicObject = this.CreateFromScript();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            base.Session.HandleException(ex2);
            throw ex2;
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Session.trace_exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but the empty try catches can be replaced with an if block using `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the call to `GetEnumerator()`:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    bool entryXRight = false;
    // ...
}
```

---

As a side note, that code needs a lot of love, like changing those `throw ex;` to `throw;` and getting rid of the `goto`.

Comment: I've been dong .NET since beta 2 of 1.0....I think that's the first time I've seen a `goto` (outside of examples)......

Comment: @Tim I almost used one in C++ today, but luckily found another way out.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is raised because `IEnumerator` itself does not implement `IDisposable`. The latter is necessary if you want to use the object in a `using` statement since `using` is translated into a `try/finally` block, and in this `finally` block the `IDisposable.Dispose` method of the object should be called.

The code looks weird all together, there is even a `goto`! But what that code actually does is

- create an empty `Chimney` array if there are no rows
- otherwise do a `foreach` over the rows (executing what's inside the `while (enumerator.MoveNext){}` loop)

So it can be converted to this:

```
DataTable dataTable = this.ChimneyTable; 
// changes start here
this.oChimneys = new Chimney[dataTable.Rows.Count];
int num = 0;

foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    // the part in the loop while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    num++; // was the last line... for orientation
}
// end of changes
IL_247: // superflous, just for your orientation
```

Comment: You could even remove the if-else entirely without changing semantics.

Comment: Was there ever a time in .NET's history where IEnumerator implemented IDisposable? I'm surprised this code ever compiled.

Comment: @n8wrl maybe the `using` pattern was a little different so that it only cared if a `Dispose` method is there, no matter wether from interface or the specific class itself.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerator` does not implement `IDisposable`. `IEnumerator<T>` does but that is a different type.

Remove the `using` part of that line and the accompanying block.